# Adding multiple integers using arguments in function

Tags: c

I am learning function in C. I want to sum multiple integers using arguments in function. I managed to write a code for adding two integers, but how if I want to add multiple integers and print the total of them? please guide me. Code which i wrote is;

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int sum(int a, int b, int c);
int main (void){
    int x,y,z;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter first integer to add.\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("Enter second integer to add.\n");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    sum(x, y, z);
    printf("Total = %d.\n",sum(x, y, z));
    getch();
    return 0;
}

int sum (int a, int b, int c){
    c=a+b;
    return c;
}
```

Comment: replace the body of `sum` with `return a+b+c;`. i'll let them explain why.

Comment: What is you goal? Having a function with is able to add an arbitrary number of values?

Comment: I am sorry. I want take multiple inputs from user and when he press 'q' it should give me total of all integers he gave, i mean total of all integers taken from user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
sum = 0;

while (ch == "y")
{
scanf("%d", &a);
sum+=a;
printf("Do you want to continue: ");
scanf("%c\n", &ch);
}

printf("%d", sum);
```

- The idea is to have a variable sum whose initial value is 0.
- Have a while loop that takes a integer a as input & add it to sum.
- You can mantain a variable ch, which can be used to exit out of the loop. Only if the user enters "y", the user will be asked for integer again.

Comment: should be scanf("%d", &a); and scanf("%d", &ch)

Comment: @Mithrandir, oops, wrote in a hurry.

Answer (score 2):

try this  !

```
int main()
{
int var[100];
int count = 5;

printf("enter number %d number ", count);
for( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
{
    scanf( "%d", &var[i] );
}

printf("sum=%d", sum(var, count) );

return 0;
 }


int sum( int var[], int count )
{
int sum = 0;
for( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
{
    sum += var[i];
}

return sum;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks it work. But i dont want to bound the user that he must enter 5 integers. i want it unlimited

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're overwriting the third argument to the function with the sum of the first two and return it. This should probably change a bit.

Just think about how you'd write a sum of three numbers in mathematics and you should see the solution.